# Reshaping multicolumn dataframe into single row with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I have a dataframe looking like this

```
name value1 value2 value3
X      1 .    2 .   6
Y      2 .    5 .   7
```

Is there a way to make this into a single row dataframe using dplyr?

```
x_value1 x_value2 x_value3 y_value1 y_value2 y_value3
```

I tried using spread but it complains about the multiple columns value1 to value3.

Thx
c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by `gather`ing into 'long' format, `unite` the 'name', 'key' columns and then do the `spread`

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1, key, value, -name) %>%
    unite(namekey, name, key) %>% 
    spread(namekey, value)
#   X_value1 X_value2 X_value3 Y_value1 Y_value2 Y_value3
#1        1        2        6        2        5        7
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, thanks! this is probably a stupid question, but can you tell me what the key and value columns would be in my case .in the gather function?

Comment: @clog14 `gather` converts the column from 'wide' to 'long', by specifying 'key', 'value', the column names goes into the 'key' column and the values into the 'value' column.  It is just that I used '`key/value`  You can create it as `a/b` or `a1/b1` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since a `data.frame` is just a list of lists, you don't need anything fancy to do this. The plain old concatenation function `c` can do it for you. Calling `c` directly won't work because that will just return the data frame, but `do.call` will splice a list of arguments into actual arguments, so `do.call(c(df))` will do what you want.

```
> df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(3), y = rnorm(3), z = rnorm(3))
> df
            x         y          z
1 -0.02600453 1.5596611  0.1419269
2  0.61540806 1.0944946  0.7526085
3 -0.79033738 0.1369467 -0.1867725
> do.call(c, df)
         x1          x2          x3          y1          y2 
-0.02600453  0.61540806 -0.79033738  1.55966113  1.09449457 
         y3          z1          z2          z3 
 0.13694672  0.14192691  0.75260853 -0.18677246
```

If you absolutely *want* to use `dplyr`, then I guess you could do

```
df %>% do.call(c, .)
```

;)